# How to get data from one php page using ajax and pass it to another php page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get data from one php page and pass it to another page using Ajax.

**JS :**

```
$.ajax({
      url: "action.php",
      success: function(data){           
        $.ajax({
             url: "data.php?id=data"
      }
});
```

**action.php :**

```
<?php    
    $test=  1;
?>
```

**data.php :**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="" src="action.js"></script>
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34935798/2943403

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to `echo` your data in **action.php**, and second, use `data` parameter of AJAX request to send data to **data.php**.

Here's the reference:

- [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

So the organization of pages should be like this:

**JS :**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "action.php",
    success: function(data){ 
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            data: {id: data},
            success: function(data){ 
                // your code
                // alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**action.php :**

```
<?php
    $test = 1;
    echo $test;
?>
```

**data.php :**

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: the id is not being passed to the data.php page

Comment: @tomtom94 data is being passed to **data.php**. Uncomment this line `// alert(data);` in AJAX request and you'll see the `$id` value.

Comment: i did and its still not displaying

Comment: @tomtom94 Oh, then remove these two scripts lines `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="" src="action.js"></script>` from **data.php** and see what you're getting. I've also updated my answer. See the **data.php :** section of my answer.

Comment: the alert still does not run

Comment: @tomtom94 That's because you probably have something else in **action.php** and **data.php** page, and you're outputting something else apart from usual `echo` things. Debug these two pages.

Comment: thanks it alerts the number out now, how would i store the alerted value in a variable in data.php

Comment: @tomtom94 You're displaying the *alerted value* inside your js code, whereas the actual variable, `$id` is in different **data.php** page. What exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to pass the value from action.php to data.php

Comment: @tomtom94 You're getting the required data in **data.php** using `$id = $_GET['id'];`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

To get data as response in ajax call, you need to `echo` the result from your php page; *action.php* page.

```
echo $test =  1;
```

In your provided code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "data.php?id=data"
}       // closing bracket is missing
```

you are sending the string data as `id` to *data.php* page. Instead you have to append the result with the url using `+` symbol like shown in the below code.

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "action.php",
   success: function(data){           
    $.ajax({
         url: "data.php?id="+data
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried doing this and the data does not show up on my data.php page

Comment: Is the data getting passed though the URL?? If so there may be some error in your data.php page.

Comment: no the id does not show up but I am trying to append it on so then i can use php $_get to access it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)** method to get/send data :

```
$.get("action.php",{}, function(data){
    //data here contain 1
    $.get("data.php", {id: data}, function(id){
         alert(id);
    }
});
```

Just echo `$test` since just the data printed in page will return as responce to the query request.

**action.php :**

```
<?php    
    $test=1;
    echo $test;
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the data is not being displayed on my data.php

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
<a href="#" class="dataClass" data-value="1">Test</a>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="" src="action.js"></script>
```

**action.js**

```
$('.dataClass').click(function(){
    var value=$(this).attr('data-value');
    $.ajax({url:"Ajax_SomePage.php?value="+value,cache:false,success:function(result){
        alert("success");
    }});
});
```

**Ajax_SomePage.php**

```
<?php
$value = $_GET['value'];
echo $value;
?>
```