# how to pass url to another page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a product Id from my products.php page to my productType.php using ajax.

**`products.php`**

```
<?php
$test = $_GET['id'];
echo $test;
?>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="" src="action.js"></script>
```

productType.php

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id;
?>
```

action.js

```
$.ajax({
  url: "products.php",
  success: function(data){ 
    $.ajax({
      url: "productsType.php?id="+data,
      success: function(data){ 
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: **For a kind attention to all of you**. Mr TomTom94 is not trying at all. He asked similar question 2 hours before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058794/how-to-get-data-from-one-php-page-using-ajax-and-pass-it-to-another-php-page-usi. And, he asked 6 questions overall in SO and didn't accepted any answer.

Comment: Both, products and productTypes could be retrieved in simple API call. What is the purpose of using nested API calls ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar then it is a dupe to close it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it into variable:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "products.php",
  success: function(data){ 
    $.ajax({
      url: "productsType.php?id=" + data,
      //------------------------^^^^^^^^^
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Correct! But what is the point of having nested API calls ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Ask the OP. `:(` There could be several reasons. As I could see, this is a valid use-case, but improper request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate:

```
url: "productsType.php?id="+data,
```

or you can use `data:{}` option of ajax:

```
url: "productsType.php",
data:{id:data}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code with async:false

```
$.ajax({
  url: "products.php",
  async:false,
  success: function(data){ 
    $.ajax({
     async:false,
      url: "productsType.php?id=" + data,
    });
  }
});
```